# How to auto refresh web page while using Nitrous.io Mac App

Tags: google-chrome, nitrousio

I am using the mac app and syncing works great.  Wondering if there is a chrome extension that will auto refresh my webpage when the sync is complete.

Comment: This depends on what framework you are developing with. There are certain frameworks (e.g. Meteor) which will automatically refresh when files are updated, and it could be possible with the framework you are using.